# Pass -XX option to JNI_CreateJavaVM

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface

I tried to use the following code to pass option to JNI_CreateJavaVM() :

```
auto options = std::string{"-XX:+UseMembar -Djava.class.path="} + clspath;
jvm_options.optionString = const_cast<char *>(options.c_str());
args.options = &jvm_options;
args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;
int rv;
rv = JNI_CreateJavaVM(jvm, reinterpret_cast<void **>(&env_), &args);
```

rv was -6 after the call.

How should I pass the option ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the option can be passed through environment variable JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS

Answer (score 0):

I see you've solved your problem in a different way, but here's why your code didn't work. You're passing two options in one option argument. As the documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#JNI_CreateJavaVM says

> The options field is an array of the following type:
>
> ```
> typedef struct JavaVMOption {
>     char *optionString;  /* the option as a string in the default platform encoding */
>     void *extraInfo;
> } JavaVMOption;
> ```

Note the "array" part. Put `-XX:+UseMembar` and `-Djava.class.path=...` in separate strings in `jvm_options[0]` and `jvm_options[1]` and set `args.nOptions = 2`